# How to refer XML document in an XSLT in OSB 11g

Tags: xml, osb

How can I refer an XML document in an XSLT in OSB. I have a xml document in my resource folder now I would like to refer this in one of my XSLT and based on some logic I would pick up values from this XMl document and pass the same into another XSLT.

Comment: I'm not even sure you can do this. XSLT describes the way you want to transform an XML document. Why would you want an actual XML file in it?

Comment: I need to use this for mapping purpose. For example in my request I receive a whole bunch of data from front end, now the backend requires data in their own format which I need to transform based on this XML document that I have.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to rename it to .xq or .xsl and [put the XML in](https://technology.amis.nl/2011/02/07/ways-to-instantiate-a-variable-in-oracle-service-bus-based-on-a-static-xml-document/) as a literal.  OSB can then execute that and assign it to a variable for you to use later.

Alternatively, you can mess around with a java class to do so, [like this](https://gibaholms.wordpress.com/2012/02/23/read-xml-resource-in-oracle-service-bus-11g/).

Comment: Thanks Trent for your ans, but is there any way I can do it without changing it to .xq or making use of any java class, I just want to reference my XML document in an XSLT, I tried using the document() function of XSLT and assign it to a variable so that whenver I require I can make use of the Variable and traverse through the XML doc but it is not working in OSB, or I might not be using the correct syntax for the document() function to refer the xml doc in OSB.

Comment: Not in 11G. Probably not in 12C either, but I haven't checked.

Comment: How do I do it by renaming it to .xq. Is there any way I can include a .xq inside an XSLT in OSB

Comment: no, they're pretty separate. I'm sure there's tricks to load a separate file using xslt as well.

Comment: Well thanks but I have been searching for that trick only, with the help of which I can include or make a reference of that xquery by my XSLT. Meanwhile can you help me out with one more thing I am not able to convert sting into nodelist in OSB even when I use node-set function it throws an error

Comment: Error executing the XSLT transformation: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: For extension function, could not find method weblogic.apache.xml.dtm.ref.DTMNodeIterator.node-set([ExpressionContext,] ).